# Different use of “Make something [adjective]."

Tags: meaning

Use of the structure “Make something [adjective]” confuses me in sometimes. I wonder if use of it below correct .

> I made lights solar-powered.

In this sentence i want to convert my house’s lights into solar powered lights.

Does this sentence have same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

- I made my lights **into** solar-powered lights. [or ones]

The idiom is: to make something **into** something else.

The kids hated spinach. So we made eating it into a game. :)

Comment: I thought make something + adj gives same meaning in this sentence ,as “solar-powered “ is adjective . Is it totally wrong or does it give different meaning ?

Comment: Not in this case. made something into something =transform something. [not give meaning, have meaning].I made my sheets into a duvet cover. I made his clothes into a costume.

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot .